# How to increase speed in sql string when insert to ms access datebase

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access, progress-bar

I have text file, its size about 3mb(15,000 strings), i inserted from text file. Processing takes 30 minutes. How can i increase speed of ms access Database.And i want progress bar, if it's processing is too long.

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();         
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {                
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName);
            BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs);
            {
                metroProgressBar1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(sr.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < sr.Length; i++)
                {                        
                    metroProgressBar1.Value++;
                }              
                string s;
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {                        
                        try
                        {
                            string pattern = @"[\d]{1,8}([.,][\d]{1,4})?";

                            Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
                            Match m = r.Match(s.Substring(77, 41));
                            while (m.Success)
                            {
                                //Console.WriteLine(m);
                                m = m.NextMatch();
                            }
                            string[] row1 = { 
                                        s.Substring(46, 31), 
                                        s.Substring(77, 41), 
                                        s.Substring(118, 8), 
                                        s.Substring(127, 10), 
                                        s.Substring(138, 10) 
                                    };
                            metroListView1.Items.Add(s.Substring(0, 45)).SubItems.AddRange(row1);
                            string cmdstr = "INSERT into GGG (event_id, device_id, parameter_id, parameter_int_id, time_id, clock_id, user_id) VALUES ('" + s.Substring(0, 45) + "', '" + s.Substring(46, 31) + "', '" + s.Substring(77, 41) + "', '" + r.Match(s.Substring(77, 41)) + "',  '" + s.Substring(118, 19) + "', '" + s.Substring(118, 8) + "',  '" + s.Substring(138, 10) + "')";
                            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
                            try
                            {
                                con.Open();
                                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                con.Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Error", ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Содержимое файла не соответствует формату таблицы");
                        }
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are executing 15000 inserts which should not take more than a couple of minutes unless you are running on a 8086 processor. First thing you may try is to insert several records in each invocation. Try this and see what the impact is.

Comment: As a side note, you should put your string insertions into parameters as well.

Comment: You can use a text driver and insert the whole lot in one sql statement.

Comment: @Fionnuala is right ! try this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f576c4a-5e07-450c-bc15-0c0732707673/sqlbulkcopy-with-ms-access?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Answer (score 1):

Use single connection for your DB operations. In your code snippet you are opening `OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);` for each line in file.

It should be something like:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  // Do the job here
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: He can leave the connection open throughout the process as well.

Comment: @jdl134679 Sure. Code snippet above only show the idea, production quality code should be based on the questioner tasks of course.